# Why don't value types require @escaping or explicit self as opposed to escaping closures?

Tags: swift, closures

So this code is is an escaping closure and I do understand that it's @escaping is required because the function escapes and appends or changes completion handlers.

```
var completionHandlers: [() -> Void] = []
func someFunctionWithEscapingClosure(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
completionHandlers.append(completionHandler)
}

func someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
closure()
}

class SomeClass {
var x = 10
func doSomething() {
    someFunctionWithEscapingClosure { self.x = 100 }
    someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure { x = 200 }
}
}

let instance = SomeClass()
instance.doSomething()
print(instance.x)
// Prints "200"

completionHandlers.first?()
print(instance.x)
// Prints "100”
```

This simple code however doesn't require the value type to be marked as escaped even though it changed the variable x.

```
var x: Int = 0

func x (y: Int) {
x += y
}

x (y: 7)

print (x)
```

This confuses me because I don't understand why in the second code self can be assessed implicitly, but with an escaping closure self is required (if it were called).

Comment: In your second example, there is no closure. So there's nothing to mark as `@escaping`. It's just a function (though confusingly named `x` like your variable). Only closure parameters need to be marked as `@escaping`. Perhaps I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 1):

> I do understand that it's @escaping is required because the function escapes and appends or changes completion handlers.

It's not entirely clear from that phrase that you understand what `@escaping` means. It means that this *function parameter* gets *stored* rather than executed immediately and thrown away.

That is what happens in your first example: we are handed a `() -> Void` and instead of merely executing it, we append it to a persistent array.

In your second example, there is no *function parameter* (just a lowly Int) so the matter never arises.

The *reason* why the question arises for a function parameter is that functions are closures, so when a function gets stored, other stuff from its environment can get stored. That can have unintended consequences, so you have to acknowledge that you're aware of this by saying `@escaping`.

Comment: (By the way, a function is a reference type, not a value type. That actually is part of the reason we have to acknowledge when escaping is taking place.)

Comment: but what about passing class instances to functions? They are reference types and don't require @escaping to be noted even when it is appended to a variable outside the function.

Comment: Did you read my answer? A class instance not a function. So it's not a closure.